# UTF-8 symbol written to the terminal output

Tags: c++, utf-8, character-encoding, char

I've been trying to understand the working principle of the `operator<<` of `std::cout` in C++. I've found that it prints UTF-8 symbols, for instance:
The simple program is:

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned char t[] = "ي";
unsigned char m0 = t[0];
unsigned char m1 = t[1];

int main()
{
    std::cout << t << std::endl;           // Prints ي
    std::cout << (int)t[0] << std::endl;   // Prints 217
    std::cout << (int)t[1] << std::endl;   // Prints 138
    std::cout << m0 << std::endl;          // Prints �
    std::cout << m1 << std::endl;          // Prints �
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95f3f51e17e4b96a)

How does the terminal that produces output determine that it must interpret `t` as a single symbol `ي`, but not as two symbols `� �`?

Comment: You need to define the environment in which this code executes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are dealing with two different types, `unsigned char[]` and `unsigned char`.
If you were to do `sizeof` on `t`, you'd find that it occupied
three bytes, and `strlen( t )` will return 2.  On the other
hand, `m0` and `m1` are single characters.

When you output a `unsigned char[]`, it is converted to an
`unsigned char*`, and the stream outputs all of the bytes until
it encounters a `'\0'` (which is the third byte in `t`).  When
you output an `unsigned char`, the stream outputs just that
byte.  So in your first line, the output device receives
2 bytes, and then the end of line.  In the last two, it receives
1 byte, and then the end of line.  And that byte, followed by
the end of line, is not a legal UTF-8 character, so the display
device displays something to indicate that there was an error,
or that it did not understand.

When working with UTF-8 (or any other multibyte encoding), you
cannot extract single bytes from a string and expect them to
have any real meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal is determining how to display the bytes you are feeding it. You are feeding it a newline (`std::endl`) between the two bytes of the 2-byte UTF-8-encoded Unicode character. Instead of this:

```
std::cout << m0 << std::endl;       // Prints �
std::cout << m1 << std::endl;       // Prints �
```

Try this:

```
std::cout << m0 << m1 << std::endl; // Prints ي
```

Why do `m0` and `m1` print as `�` in your original code?
Because your code is sending the bytes `[217, 110, 138, 110]`, which is not interpretable as UTF-8. (Assuming `std::endl` corresponds to the `\n` character, value 110.)